# LINQ with groupby and count, plus Name

Tags: c#, linq

I want to display a list with owners Name and number of lists for each.
The group.Key gives me the id of the person but how can i switch it for the name?

```
// Get all lists owned by an organization
var lists = context.SalesToolsLists.Include(x=>x.OwningUserOrganization).Where(x => uoids.Contains(x.OwningUserOrganization.Id));

// Get a dataset where each row contains OwningUserOrganization.FullName, group.Key and group.Count()
res.UOListCounts = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
foreach (var listgroup in lists?.GroupBy(info => info.OwningUserOrganizationId).Include(x=>x)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Metric = group.Key,
            Count = group.Count(),
          
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Metric))
{
    res.UOListCounts.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(listgroup.Metric, listgroup.Count));
}
```

Comment: `GroupBy(info => new { id =  info.OwningUserOrganizationId, name = info.Name})` assuming name is on the info variable

Comment: Side note (and this is my opinion), it may improve code readability to move the query out of the foreach and into its own variable.

Comment: Thanks for all help!
gunr2171,  Thats true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to group items by name instead of `OwningUserOrganizationId` as follows:

```
foreach (var listgroup in lists?.GroupBy(info => info.OwningUserOrganization.FullName).Include(x=>x)
        .Select(group => new
        {
            Metric = group.Key,
            Count = group.Count(),
          
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Metric))
{
    res.UOListCounts.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(listgroup.Metric, listgroup.Count));
}
```

So that `group.Key` gives to `OwningUserOrganization.FullName`

And as a bonus as **@gunr2171** pointed out on comments, you can move query out of the foreach and into its own variable to improve code readability.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! Works beautifully!